# Resize image dynamically based on text height

Tags: html, css, angular, web, sass

I want to make a user card for the front-end im currently making and our/my approach for that was to resize the user image based on the width given, but we noticed especially on large screens the Image gets really big while the text remains small.

I created a small mock-up in adobe xd how I image it to look like :
[User-Card Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9heJ.png)

What is common approach to this?
The only way I could imagine is to make a media query every 100 or 200px and that would be annoying as you can imagine.
This can't be that annoying right?

We're using Angular with SCSS and also used a lot of Bootstrap 4 but kinda want to get away from bootstrap.

This is the HTMl of our component before I tried changing it :

```
<div class="mb-3" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="openModal(user)">
<div class="row" >

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
        <img class="rounded" width="90%" style="object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden" [src]="user.avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 ml-n4 w-100">
        <h3 [title]="user.name" class="text mb-0 border-bottom w-100 trunc">{{ user.name }}</h3>
        <div>
            <h4 class="text mb-0">{{ user.jobTitle }}</h4>
            <h6 class="text mb-0">{{ user.hiredAt | date }}</h6>
            <span class ="badge badge-primary">{{ user.department }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I hope this question isn't that stupid.

Comment: Have you tried the css calc() function? One of my favorite uses is for dynamically resizing images vs using media queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()

Comment: Yes. Well something similar. in SASS you can use basic calculations from the get go. But the problem is I wouldnt know how much space the text takes in height. So how can I calculate with that?

Comment: How does that impact the rest of the website? Isn't that a "dirty" workaround? At least it sounds weird to me.

Comment: How about just using `vw` for you `font-size` unit. `font-size: 2vw` Edit: I read wrong. You want to change the pic size based on font size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to scale both up and down on responsiveness, set the CSS width property to 100% and height to auto
`

```
    <img class="rounded responsive" width="90%" style="object-fit: cover; overflow: hidden" [src]="user.avatar">
</div>`
```

`.responsive { width: 100%; height: auto; }`

Comment: thats what we did but as I said when the screen gets bigger the image will get bigger too but the text won't. At least not "unified".

Comment: Can you share any screenshot??

Comment: So what I understand you want to resize image only based on the text, Not based on the screen?  share the screenshot of current image

Comment: Yeah sure.
Thats how it looks like on big screens with 100% width : https://ibb.co/h7S7q5G